# Powershell: Pipeline Producer and Consumer communication

Tags: powershell, pipeline, producer-consumer, throttling

Environment: Win10 + Powershell 5.1

I have a producer function and a consumer function. I used pipeline to connect them.
The producer function create a new object every 5 seconds, while the consumer function might take longer to consume an object within 5 seconds. Consumer function has the ability to deal with 3 objects.
Is there a way for the consumer to let producer know that producer needs to wait until consumer has additional capacity?

This is my code. Populate-NextIcon = Producer and Launch-Icon = consumer

```
Populate-NextIcon -List $list| foreach-object { $_ | Launch-Icon }

function Populate-NextIcon
{
param ([System.Collections.ArrayList]$list)

foreach($i in $list)
{
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name = $i.name; x = $i.x; y= $i.y }
  sleep
}

}

function Launch-Icon
{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName )]
                [String]$name,
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName )]
                [int]$x,
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName )]
                [int]$y              
        )

....do something to launch the icon
}
```

Comment: You can use the `-OutBuffer` common parameter to batch output items, but it won't work well here since you're wrapping the call to `Launch-Icon` in `ForEach-Object { ... }` - is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Hello Mathias, Yes there's a reason. My consumer function is to move mouse and click the application icon to launch them, which may or may not success. I use the other scanner in the backend to check which applications have been launched. This consumer is only used to "move mouse and click". In my producer function, it's a while($true) loop which is endless. I also defined a script block to start-job at the backend. Only when all applications are launched, this job will be killed

Comment: For `Launch-Icon` to receive pipeline input _one by one_, as it is being emitted by the producer, you must place the input-processing code inside a `process { ... }` block - see [`about_Functions_Advanced`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced). Once you do that, you don't `ForEach-Object` anymore and can connect the two commands _directly_: `Populate-NextIcon -List $list | Launch-Icon`.

Comment: @Mathias, good point re not needing `ForEach-Object` (assuming that `Launch-Icon` has a `process` block, which seems to be the problem here). However, timing of output-object creation on the _producer's_ side aside, `-OutBuffer` has no bearing on how the _consumer_ receives objects, because even with `-OutBuffer` the buffered objects are ultimately sent _one by one_.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm aware, I was just trying to fish for the actual question (since the problem as described here appears ... imagined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's **nothing you need to do to throttle the upstream command in a pipeline** (assuming it is a PowerShell command) - PowerShell will automatically block the producer (the upstream cmdlet) until the consumer (the downstream cmdlet) is ready to accept more input.

Consider the following example:

```
& { while ($true) { (++$i) } } | ForEach-Object { "[$_]"; Start-Sleep 1 }
```

This produces an infinite sequence of numbers, outputting a new number every second.

See the bottom section for details.

---

Note that PowerShell's common **[`-OutBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#outbuffer)** parameter **only controls buffering on the *producer* side** (and therefore does *not* apply here); that is, it allows a cmdlet to produce a batch of output of objects *before* PowerShell sends them through the pipeline - whereas by default each object is sent immediately when output (see the bottom section for details).
Note that, perhaps surprisingly, `-OutBuffer <n>` means that output starts only once the `<n>`<sup>nth</sup> *`+ 1`* object is created. In other words:  the default behavior is equal to `-OutBuffer 0`, and `-OutBuffer 1` means that once a *2nd* object is created, the objects are sent.

While this alters the *timing* of when objects are sent through the pipeline, the basic mechanism remains the same: once a batch of objects is ready, the objects are sent *one by one*.

This parameter is rarely used, but it can be useful in cases where a slow consumer (downstream cmdlet) would unduly throttle a producer, and you want to producer to produce objects ahead of time; this allows a producer to produce its batches more quickly, ahead of time.

---

As for **what you tried**:

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, there is no reason to use the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet in a pipeline connecting two pipeline-processing cmdlets - just use
`Populate-NextIcon -List $list| Launch-Icon`

However, this **assumes that `Launch-Icon` uses a `process { ... }` block for per-input-object processing**, the absence of which is most likely the problem in your case.

**Without such a block, your function body implicitly behaves like an `end { ... }` block, which means that it won't be invoked until after *all* input has been received** - and, assuming input actually ends, your pipeline-binding parameter variables will at that point reflect only the *last* input object - see [`about_Functions_Advanced`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced).
In effect - if the (implied) `end` block is ever called, which with an *infinite* producer will *not* happen - this omission limits your function to processing at most a *single* object received from the pipeline.

You *bypassed* the problem with the missing `process` block with your `ForEach-Object` call, by effectively creating a *nested, single-input-object* pipeline, whose only input object is the single `ForEach-Object` input object *at hand*.

While this doesn't impede *functionality* per se, it slows down your command needlessly and noticeably.

---

**How data flows through the PowerShell pipeline**:

***Traditional shell* pipelines**, such as in POSIX-like shells on Unix, are based on:

- ***inter-process*** communication (programs running in *child processes* communicate)
- sending ***raw byte data*,** with data being passed in ***chunks of bytes*** (buffers of a fixed size, typically 64KB).

By contrast, [**PowerShell's pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) is based on:

- ***in-process*** *method calls* on **specialized .NET classes** called ***cmdlets*** (which equally applies to *binary* cmdlets typically compiled from C# and written-in-PowerShell cmdlets a.k.a. [*advanced functions / scripts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced))
- sending **data as *objects*** (instances of .NET types), which are always **passed *one by one***:

  - as soon as they're being emitted, by default
  - with `-OutputBuffer` optionally controlling how many objects are produced first

Note: **When *external programs* participate** in a PowerShell pipeline:

- they run in *child processes*, of necessity
- only *text*-based communication (strings) is supported, where *lines of text* constitute the *objects* that flow through the pipeline one by one, which applies both to data *received* from an external program, and data that PowerShell commands *send to* an external program.
- **Caveat**: As of PowerShell 7.1:

  - There is ***no* support for sending *raw byte data* through the pipeline** - see [GitHub issue #1908](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908)
  - **Sending a single string *to* an external program invariably causes a *trailing newline* to be appended** - see [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974).

---

**Communication between *cmdlets* in the pipeline**:

Binary cmdlets *receive* pipeline input - object by object - via the [`Cmdlet.ProcessRecord()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.processrecord#System_Management_Automation_Cmdlet_ProcessRecord) method (note the unexpected use of the term *record* in the name, which, however, cannot be changed anymore).

In *PowerShell code*, the equivalent is:

- in advanced functions / scripts: the `process { ... }` block inside the function / script body.
- in (the rarely used) `filter` functions: the entire function body

*Sending* pipeline input *typically* happens in the *same* method / block (using the `.WriteObject()` method in binary cmdlets, and either implicit output or (rarely needed) `Write-Output` calls), although cmdlets that must *aggregate* all of their input before they can produce output, such as `Sort-Object`, must defer output until their `.EndProcessing()` method / `end` block is called.

When two *PowerShell commands* are connected in a pipeline - let's call them *producer* and *consumer* (from a given command's perspective, the general terms for referring to commands that come *earlier* / *later* in a pipeline  are *upstream* / *downstream* commands), their specific interaction is as follows:

- When the producer outputs (sends) an object (which may not happen instantly if `-OutBuffer` is involved), the consumer's `.ProcessRecord` method / `process` block is called.
- This happens *synchronously*, i.e. the producer's execution is *blocked* until the receiver's method / block call finishes.

This means that **pacing consumers and receivers to avoid runaway output production in the consumer that a receiver cannot keep up with is built into PowerShell's infrastructure** (assuming *intra-command* code that executes synchronously, as is typical).

Here's a **minimal example** that uses a *simple* function as the producer and a `filter` function as the receiver; however, the same principles apply to cmdlets:

```
# A simple produces function that produces a number sequence indefinitely.
# Write-Output is equivalent to calling .WriteObject() from a binary cmdlet.
# (It is used here explicitly to highlight when output happens, 
#  though note that explicit Write-Output use  is rarely necessary.)
function Invoke-Producer { 
  while ($true) { Write-Output ++$i; Write-Verbose -vb 'back in producer' } 
}

# A simply receiver filter function that echoes each input object and
# indefinitely waits for user input before continuing.
# The filter's body acts like a ProcessRecord() / process block implementation.
filter Invoke-Receiver { "`nReceived: $_"; Read-Host 'Press Enter to continue' }

Invoke-Producer | Invoke-Receiver
```

You'll see the following once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which shows that control isn't returned to the producer until the receiver has finished processing each object:

```
Received: 1
Press Enter to continue:

VERBOSE: back in producer

Received: 2
Press Enter to continue:
```

**Caveat**: This **automatic pacing does *not* apply when *external programs* act as producers** when combined with a PowerShell command acting as the receiver (as of PowerShell 7.1):

PowerShell *buffers* output lines from external programs if the receiver cannot keep up, which means that at least hypothetically you could run out of memory.

You can verify this behavior as follows on Unix (macOS or Linux); make sure that no `find` process is currently running:

```
$notified = $false

# Using `find`, list the paths of all file-system items in PowerShell's 
# home directory and echo one by one, waiting fora half-second after each.
find $PSHOME | ForEach-Object { 
  "[$_]"
  if (-not $notified -and -not (Get-Process -ea Ignore find)) { 
    Write-Verbose -vb "FIND HAS EXITED."
    $notified = $true
  }
  Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 500
}
```

You'll see something like the following, which implies that PowerShell has buffered all of `find`'s output behind the scenes (as a result of which `find` then exited), before the `ForEach-Object` command has processed it all:

```
[/Users/jdoe/.powershell]
[/Users/jdoe/.powershell/Microsoft.CSharp.dll]
VERBOSE: FIND HAS EXITED.
[/Users/jdoe/.powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll]
...
```

Note that **there are scenarios where even a *PowerShell* receiver could run out of memory** with an infinite producer, namely:

- if the PowerShell command needs to aggregate all input first.
- if the PowerShell command is a *simple* function / script that accesses pipeline input via the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input), whose use means that PowerShell buffers all input up front.

For instance, the following command will run out of memory, because processing of the simple `foo` function's body doesn't start until *all input has been collected*, which by definition never happens here:

```
# Simple function that, due to use of $input, relies on PowerShell
# to collect all its pipeline input *up front*.
# Note: The body of a simple function / script is implicitly the
#       equivalent of the `.EndProcessing()` method / `end` block of a
#       cmdlet.
function foo { $input | % { "[$_]" } }

# !! Never produces output, and eventually runs out of memory.
& { while ($true) { (++$i) } } | foo
```

Comment: how such a comprehensive answer had only 1 vote?

Answer (score 0):

So:

1. ForEach-Object is unnecessary once i used the process{} block in my function.
   I thought by default the function is in the process{} block but later I found it's in the end block
2. This is very key to understand:

> once a batch of objects is ready, the objects are sent one by one

Originally due to the misusing of the process{} block, I misunderstood that the procedurer will only send the batch object once everything is ready

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, Ginger_Chacha, but note that the quote regarding a _batch_ of objects being ready only applies if `-OutBuffer` is used (with a value of `1` or higher). Without  `-OutBuffer`, outputting an object instantly sends it to the downstream cmdlet (by synchronously calling its `.ProcessRecord()` method).